# Salesforce lightning web component generating an error on a lookup field (master detail)

Tags: salesforce-lightning

I've creatd a lwc to list out records from a related record (in this case all the expenditures for a single disbursement). For existing expenditures is disable the rows so they cannot be changed. The rows contain 2 fields (General Accounting Unit and Expenditure Amount). The General accounting unit is the master-detail relationship and the existing rows populate the General accounting unit field correctly. Additionally there is button to add a row. When using the button, it won't allow me to enter/retrive an existing general accounting unit for some reason. If I click the search all then it generates the following error:

This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ma')] Failing descriptor: {markup://lightning:deprecatedOverlayUtils}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5T7M.png)

correctExpenditure.html:

```
<template>

    <template if:false={transferComplete}>
        <div class="slds-text-align_center slds-text-heading_medium">
            This disbursement has not yet been processed. You cannot correct a disbursement that has not been processed.
        </div>
        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
            <div class="slds-size_2-of-12">
                <lightning-button-group>
                    <lightning-button
                        variant="neutral"
                        label="Back"
                        title="Back"
                        onclick={cancel} >
                    </lightning-button>
                </lightning-button-group>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>

    <template if:true={transferComplete}>

        <template if:true={isLoading}>
            <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading"></lightning-spinner>
        </template>
        
        <div style="height:500px">
            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
                <div class="slds-size_10-of-12">
                    <div class="slds-text-heading_medium">Correct Expenditure</div>
                </div>

                <div class="slds-size_2-of-12">
                    <lightning-button-group>
                        <lightning-button
                            variant="neutral"
                            label="Cancel"
                            title="Cancel"
                            onclick={cancel} >
                        </lightning-button>
                        <lightning-button
                            variant="brand"
                            label="Save"
                            title="Save"
                            onclick={save} >
                        </lightning-button>
                    </lightning-button-group>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            
            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
                <template for:each={finalRecords} for:item="expenditure">
                    <div key={expenditure.Id} class="slds-size_1-of-12 slds-var-p-horizontal_small">
                        <lightning-button
                            variant="base"
                            label="Delete"
                            title="Delete"
                            onclick={removeRow}
                            id={expenditure.tempId}
                            disabled={expenditure.disabled}>
                        </lightning-button>
                    </div>
                    <div key={expenditure.Id} class="slds-size_8-of-12 slds-var-p-horizontal_small">
                        <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name={expenditureApiName}>
                            <lightning-input-field
                                id={expenditure.tempId}
                                field-name={fundApiName}
                                variant="label-stacked"
                                required="TRUE"
                                value={expenditure.Fund}
                                onchange={handleChange}
                                disabled={expenditure.disabled}>
                            </lightning-input-field>
                        </lightning-record-edit-form>
                    </div>                                       
                    <div key={expenditure.Id} class="slds-size_3-of-12 slds-var-p-horizontal_small">
                        <lightning-input
                            id={expenditure.tempId}
                            type="number"
                            name="Amount"
                            label="Expenditure Amount"
                            value={expenditure.Amount}
                            required="TRUE"
                            onchange={amountChange}
                            disabled={expenditure.disabled}>
                        </lightning-input>
                    </div>
                </template>

                <div class="slds-size_9-of-12">
                    <lightning-button
                        variant="base"
                        label="Add Row"
                        title="Add Row"
                        onclick={addRow} >
                    </lightning-button>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-size_3-of-12">
                    <template if:true={disTotal}>
                        Disbursement Total: <lightning-formatted-number value={disTotal} format-style="currency"></lightning-formatted-number>
                        <br>
                    </template>
                    Amount Allocated: <lightning-formatted-number value={totalAmount} format-style="currency"></lightning-formatted-number>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-text-align_center slds-text-color_error">
                {errorMessage}
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </template>    
</template>
```

correctExpenditure.js

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

import getExpenditures from '@salesforce/apex/correctExpenditure_CTRL.getExpenditures';
import getDisbursementTotal from '@salesforce/apex/correctExpenditure_CTRL.getDisbursementTotal';
import getAssetTransferComplete from '@salesforce/apex/correctExpenditure_CTRL.getAssetTransferComplete';
import saveRecords from '@salesforce/apex/correctExpenditure_CTRL.saveRecords';
import FUND from '@salesforce/schema/outfundsnpspext__GAU_Expenditure__c.outfundsnpspext__General_Accounting_Unit__c';
//import FUND from '@salesforce/schema/outfundsnpspext__GAU_Expenditure__c.GeneralAccountingUnitLu__c';
import AMOUNT from '@salesforce/schema/outfundsnpspext__GAU_Expenditure__c.outfundsnpspext__Amount__c';
import DISAMOUNT from '@salesforce/schema/outfunds__Disbursement__c.outfunds__Amount__c';
import ASSET_TRANSFER_COMPLETE from '@salesforce/schema/outfunds__Disbursement__c.AssetTransferComplete__c';
import EXPENDITURE_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/outfundsnpspext__GAU_Expenditure__c';

export default class CorrectExpenditure extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api recordId;

    @track records = [];
    @track distotalrecords = [];  
    @track transferrecords = [];  

    isLoading;
    transferComplete = true;
    errorMessage;
    disTotal;
    existingCount;

    get expenditureApiName(){
        return EXPENDITURE_OBJECT.objectApiName;
    }

    get fundApiName(){
        return FUND.fieldApiName;
    }    

    get finalRecords(){
        let output = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < this.records.length; i++){
            
            let rec = this.records[i];
            let value = {
                Id: rec.Id,
                Fund: rec[FUND.fieldApiName],
                Amount: rec[AMOUNT.fieldApiName],
                tempId: i,
                record: rec,
                disabled: i < this.existingCount,
            };
            if (rec[FUND.fieldApiName]){
                value.Fund = rec[FUND.fieldApiName];
            }
            console.log('value ', value, i);
            console.log('fund id ', rec[FUND.fieldApiName], i);
            output.push(value);
        }

        return output;
    }

    get totalAmount(){
        let total = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < this.records.length; i++){
            let rec = this.records[i];

            if (rec[AMOUNT.fieldApiName])
                total += rec[AMOUNT.fieldApiName];
        }

        return total;
    }

    async connectedCallback(){
        this.isLoading = true;

        //get the transfer record
        this.transferrecords = await getAssetTransferComplete({ disbursementId: this.recordId });
        let rec1 = this.transferrecords[0];
        this.transferComplete = rec1[ASSET_TRANSFER_COMPLETE.fieldApiName];       

        if (this.transferComplete === true)
        {
            //get the expenditures for the disbursement
            this.records = await getExpenditures({ disbursementId: this.recordId });
            
            this.existingCount = this.records.length;

            if (!this.records.length){
                this.addRow();
            }

            //get the disbursement total
            this.distotalrecords = await getDisbursementTotal({ disbursementId: this.recordId });
            let rec = this.distotalrecords[0];
            this.disTotal = rec[DISAMOUNT.fieldApiName];        
        }

        this.isLoading = false;
    }

    handleChange(event){
        console.log('handleChange fund drop down');
        console.log('handleChange', event.target.id, event.target.value);

        let id = event.target.id; // We want a number
        id = id.split('-')[0] * 1;

        let record = this.records[id];
        record[FUND.fieldApiName] = event.target.value;
    }

    amountChange(event){
        console.log('amountChange', event.target.id, event.target.value);

        let id = event.target.id; // We want a number
        id = id.split('-')[0] * 1;

        let record = this.records[id];
        record[AMOUNT.fieldApiName] = event.target.value * 1;
    }

    addRow(event){
        let newExpenditure = {};
        newExpenditure[FUND.fieldApiName] = this.recordId;

        this.records.push(newExpenditure);
    }

    removeRow(event){
        let id = event.target.id; // We want a number
        id = id.split('-')[0] * 1;

        try {
            this.records.splice(id, 1);

            console.log(this.records.length);
        } catch (e){
            console.error(e);
        }
    }

    async save(event){
        this.errorMessage = null;
        this.isLoading = true;

        let lookups = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field');
        for (let i = 0; i < lookups.length; i++){
            let lookup = lookups[i];
            if (!lookup.reportValidity()){
                this.errorMessage = 'A fund is required on all rows';
            }
        }

        let allInputs = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input');
        for (let input of allInputs){
            if(!input.checkValidity()){
                this.errorMessage = 'Amount is required on all values';
            }
            input.reportValidity();
        }

        if (this.totalAmount != this.disTotal){
            this.errorMessage = 'The sum of amounts must equal the amount of the disbursement before saving';
        }

        
        /*for (let i = 0; i < lookups.length; i++){
            let lookup1 = this.records[i][GLACCOUNT.fieldApiName];

            for (let j = i+1; j < lookups.length; j++){
                let lookup2 = this.records[j][GLACCOUNT.fieldApiName];

                if (lookup1 == lookup2){
                    this.errorMessage = 'Duplicate GL Accounts are not allowed';
                }
            }
        }*/

        if (this.errorMessage){
            this.isLoading = false;
            return;
        }

        try {
            await saveRecords({disbursementId: this.recordId, Expenditures: this.records});
        } catch (e){
            console.error(e);
            this.errorMessage = e.body.message;
        }

        this.isLoading = false;

        this.cancel(event);
    }

    cancel(event){
        /* let navigate = {
             type: 'standard__recordPage',
             attributes: {
                 recordId: this.recordId,
                 objectApiName: 'outfunds__Disbursement__c',
                 actionName: 'view'
             }
         }

         console.log(navigate);

         this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](navigate); */
        
        window.location.href = `/${this.recordId}`;
    }
}
```

I've also noticed in the console log that the handleChange event is never even firing when I start typing in the general accounting unit field to try and find/select an existing one.

Anybody have any ideas on what the issue might be here?

Thanks, Jerry.

What is really odd is if I change the following line in the html file:
value={expenditure.Fund} to
value={expenditure.FUND} then the lookup works on the lines that get added when using the add row button but then the existing (first 2 rows won't get the general accounting unit field populated).

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. In the following code:

```
addRow(event){
    let newExpenditure = {};
    newExpenditure[FUND.fieldApiName] = this.recordId;
```

The field `FUND` in the `newExpenditure[FUND.fieldApiName] = this.recordId;`
was not a valid field type in the expenditure record. This should have been a disbursement id variable and not general accounting unit variable.